# Subscribers model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider a model for keeping user id's of subscribers on a particular comment thread, such that

thread has_many subscribers

where subscribers is of type user.

I feel like generating a new a table for subscribers is overkill. In principle, I'd like to access thread.subscribers to get a list of subscribers- surely there is a 'lighter' way?

I'm using Rails 3 with SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods you could use.

Options One is to use a habtm relationship like:

```
class Thread
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

However personally I would use an additional model, so that should you even need it you can specify stuff about subscriptions:

```
class Thread
  has_many :subscriptions
end

class Subscription
  belongs_to :thread
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Generally a useful join model is considered better practice.

Additionally I wouldn't really be worrying about how 'light' you database schema is. Databases are very good at what they're good at, and that's why we let they do it. Encoding this kind of information as a string or the like as other issues and may even be less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just store it is a regular attribute on the `Thread` model, corresponding to a column in the `threads` table. Call it `subscriber_list`, and define it as a pipe-delimited list of subscribers. In the database, make it type `:text`.

Then in `Thread` just create a couple accessors:

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  def subscribers
    self.subscribers_list.split('|')
  end

  def subscribers=(arr)
    self.subscribers_list = arr.join('|')
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to be a rather bad idea. The problems associated with this approach (methods to add and remove subscribes are going to be expensive, etc) are far greater than the inconvenience of another table & model. You're also missing out on all the ActiveRecord magic. Additionally you're eventually going to run out of space in that text field.

Comment: @thomasfedb, it really depends on the use case. The OP specifically asked if there was a way to avoid creating another table, so I gave him the way. I am giving him enough credit as a programmer that he has thought it through and decided this method is better for his use case than an additional table.

Comment: fair enough. Still wouldn't touch it with a 10 foot pole. =P

Comment: @thomasfedb, FTR, I would generally not use this method either. Only when the number of elements would make the row count in a new table extremely large (in the hundreds of thousands or millions) and when the data is relatively static.

Comment: @thomasfedb, Which I suppose for a comment thread subscription, neither of these things apply. I'll upvote your answer ;)